# Avoiding misuse of SE/SO for online university tests during COVID-19

Tags: discussion, feature-request, off-topic, homework

A number of science and technology-related sites have traditionally considered homework off-topic. As far as I understand, this is because we aim to create a base of answers which are useful for multiple people, rather than just the person asking. There are also concerns about how answers to these questions could potentially help students cheat on tests. In the light of the increase in online tests due to COVID-19, Phys.SE recently had a long discussion and it became clear that several members of the community feel strongly about the need to do something: [Strict(er) adherence to homework guidelines?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12836/) (a score of 20 on that meta places it among the most well-received posts; it was tagged "featured" by a moderator).

Now, with most universities administering online examinations due to the public health concerns, there is a higher likelihood that students will attempt to misuse SE sites, and the fact remains that even though their homework and test questions are off-topic, they are frequently answered (before being closed) by users who are less familiar with the policies. Furthermore, people are always welcome to post comments even after closure of questions. Comments aren't supposed to be answers or hints, but in practical application, they often do answer the question, and fixing that problem is, again, a broader issue which requires a more carefully developed solution, which will take a long time.

The problem of people answering off-topic questions is also one which needs to be solved as a more general concern; the new close experience is working towards that goal. But that's a long-term plan, and I hope we can **quickly** temporarily implement a patch of sorts specifically targeted at solving this problem, just for the next few months while online learning progresses.

As part of the recently-shipped new user "Ask Question modal" experience, users can be shown basic guidelines of what's off-topic, so that's a potential place to warn users. But from experience, I can be sure that a student desperate for an answer to their test question will not bother reading anything on that page. It's just psychology: if they're the kind who'll cheat on a test, they wouldn't care the least about website rules. Humans in that mood instinctively dismiss all banners, warnings, and notifications with the smallest number of clicks and keystrokes possible.

---

There's no easy solution. Here is the best I came up with: before a user (regardless of rep) starts typing a question (on any site that thinks it's vulnerable to misuse as a homework-cheating service and opts-in for this process), they must be shown a banner with words like

> Due to the increase in online instruction at schools during the COVID-19 pandemic, we have enacted stricter policies on homework problems asked on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow. Please type the following statement into the textbox below to continue and ask your question:
>
> "I assert that the question I am asking does not attempt to violate the trust of any online testing service.

There's no need to block users from copy-pasting the prompt text into the textbox. There's no need to make this lawyer-proof, since it's not supposed to be a binding declaration or anything. The emphasis should be that the typed declaration must be as short as possible. It's just for the purpose of ensuring that they know homework is strictly not to be asked. I think that it's fine if they skim over the prompt text, since they will need to at least read a little bit of it and get the gist of it and properly complete the task of filling that textbox. At least most of them will get the impression that they have no hope of getting the question answered here. Remember that they're on tight schedules so they won't waste their time on long-shots like fussy websites. Furthermore, this declaration will be absolutely harmless for people who don't wish to ask something related to a test.

---

This isn't supposed to be just a feature request, since I'm welcoming other ideas of how we can **immediately** take action to ensure that SE/SO does not help students cheat on tests. If you feel we can/should do nothing about this problem, you're welcome to go ahead and write an answer to defend your view! If you have alternate systems to achieve this goal, please chime in with answers. It's important that we resolve this as soon as possible.

Comment: Your last paragraph indicates that it's the responsibility of the Stack Exchange network to mitigate academic dishonesty.  Students sign up to universities and agree to this on their own, and no one else is a party to that agreement.  Information is not given under the pretense that it's not being used to flaunt academic rules.  It's the student's responsibility to not cheat, and if they choose to do so, it's not our responsibility to restrict their access to knowledge.

Comment: So a student looking for help on an examination, has gone to the effort to write a question, is going to reverse course due to a declaration of a ethics violation?  They have already violated the anti-cheating rules at that point.  This would not prevent the low quality questions your talking about.

Answer (score 19):

Do note that Physics Stack Exchange **does allow homework questions** per their [FAQ](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) - they just expect them to be of sufficient quality and only asking for help on how to solve them. That's very different from your question which infers there's some sort of complete ban on homework questions. But I'll go ahead and answer you on homework help in general.

#### Cheating is actually valuable.

Looking up answers or asking for help has long been viewed as a form of cheating because for some reason we held this belief that being able to memorize information is actually a sign of intelligence. It definitely is not.

Many universities are realizing this lately, and most online courses don't even attempt to block cheating anymore. Online exams are considered open-book and you are *encouraged* to go look up the solution to the problem to ensure you get the best score. That is because there is a far more valuable skill than being able to memorize useless tidbits: knowing how and where to look up the information when you don't know it.

There's even been research that shows students who encounter something they don't know and have to look it up tend to remember the information better than those who tried to memorize it using the regurgitation method before starting the test. It's similar to encountering something in a real-life situation rather than wondering how something will ever apply to you in the future.

#### The real problem is plagiarism.

Looking up the correct information is perfectly fine. *Copying* that information as if it was yours is a serious problem. And detecting when a student has copied information from elsewhere can be virtually impossible. Some fields, especially mathematics-oriented ones, tend to have the same answers submitted by every student. Certain problems can only be solved in one way, and the steps taken to get there should always be the same. So even if a student seeks help and figures it out, there's no way to determine if they actually understand the subject now or just copied something off a page.

#### Shifting the responsibility.

I'm going to be frank: it is not our responsibility to detect and prevent plagiarism. We get contacted by universities all the time wanting details about people who have been cheating or demanding that we do something to prevent it in the future. No.

It is the responsibility of the university to fight plagiarism. While that's easier to do in the context of essays, there are still ways to help combat it at the source. Last time I took a statistics class, the testing software actually had a tool built into it that allowed you to ask for help directly in the service. This help tool would walk you through how to solve the entire problem, from beginning to the final answer, and then *give you a completely different problem to solve* in order to prove you understand the concept. The one it walked you through wouldn't count.

Obviously that's just one very basic example, but it shows that universities are perfectly capable of embracing students who need extra help and finding other ways of dealing with this problem. Expecting every website on the Internet to combat it on their behalf is completely unreasonable.

#### So, should we do anything here?

Honestly, we couldn't care less if sites have their own policies for closing and deleting questions which are clearly homework. All the power to you, we're not going to step all over the communities who have a strong, unified desire to combat this themselves. But we are definitely **not** going to implement additional checks into the Ask Question page that inconvenience every user asking a question to try and root out the tiny number asking about homework.

I'd personally prefer people stop gripping onto this fake reality of tests being some absolute indicator of intelligence or that looking up answers somehow sacrifices the integrity of the university. Because it doesn't. There's absolutely nothing wrong with people asking for help with their homework or exams. Technology has forever changed the landscape of education. Just embrace the new reality and stop fighting an unwinnable battle.

<sub>* Assuming they are not copying content which is copyrighted.</sub>

Comment: Not only do I agree with the premise of the answer you've provided, your last paragraph is more than spot on.  Imagine dealing with this circumstance when teaching (or tutoring, or proctoring) remote classes.

Comment: Looking stuff up and asking for help with some aspect of a problem is fine.  Attempting to abuse the volunteer time of skilled and experienced professionals for Google outsourcing and to answer question dumps is not.  The only thing that annoys me more is the cucumbers who serve up answers, prioitizing their own fake internet points above the integrity of the education system, disadvantaging those who work through problems and helping to turnkey out graduates who are essentially useless when facing new problems:(